# hibernate not retrieving data from database

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

hi there i'm trying to read all data from a mysql table and display it on a jsp but i cant seem to be able to retrieve any data from the table as the jsp loads with other data excluding the data from table,from me trying to find the root of the problem i found my DAO doesn't get the data from the table and as such no data is passed to the servlet and jsp, all google searches i've done i have been unable to find one that can solve my issue, any help on this matter would be highly appreciated

here is my DAO class

```
public class StudentDAO {


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        String hql = "from model.Student";
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql); //get all student objects
            students = query.list();
            System.out.println(students + "list of students"); // trying to query the problem
            System.out.println(students);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }
        return students;
    }
```

and here is my HibernateUtil class

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                Properties settings = new Properties();
                
                // Hibernate settings equivalent to hibernate.cfg.xml's properties
                settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/week05");
                settings.put(Environment.USER, "user1");
                settings.put(Environment.PASS, "user1");
                settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
                settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
                settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");
                settings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create-drop");
                configuration.setProperties(settings);
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Student.class);//jpa entity mapping
                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
                
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

here is my servlet class incase i configured it wrongly:

```
@WebServlet({ "/", "/new", "/edit", "/update", "/delete", "/insert" })
public class StudentServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    private StudentDAO studentDao;
    String home = "/Week05";

    public StudentServlet() {
        this.studentDao = new StudentDAO();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String sPath = request.getServletPath();
        //switch statement to call appropriate method
        switch (sPath) {
            case "/new":
                try {
                    showNewForm(request, response);
                } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case "/insert":
                try {
                    insertStudent(request, response);
                } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                break;
            case "/delete":
                try {
                    deleteStudent(request, response);
                } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case "/update":
                try {
                    updateStudent(request, response);
                } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case "/edit":
                try {
                    editStudent(request, response);
                } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            default:
                try {
                    listAllStudents(request, response); //home page 
                } catch (ServletException | IOException | SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                break; 
            } 
    }
 // functions to fetch data from studentDao and display data on appropriate jsp
    private void listAllStudents(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
        List<Student> allStudents = studentDao.getAllStudents();
        request.setAttribute("listStudents", allStudents);
        System.out.println(allStudents+"hello");
        RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp"); //home page  | list all objects from table
        dispatch.forward(request, response);
    }
```

and here is my index.jsp just in case too

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.*" import="model.Student"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1 shink-to-fit=yes">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384...">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary pd-8">
         <a class="navbar-brand">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XYZ University</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">

            <div class="form container-fluid p-4">
               <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/new" class="btn btn-success" >Add
                    Student</a>
            </div>
            <br>
            
            <!--Assigning ArrayList object containing student data to the local object -->
            <% ArrayList<Student> studentList = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("listStudents"); %> 
            <table class="table table-bordered">
            
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <%
                     if(request.getAttribute("listStudents") != null)  {
                            Iterator<Student> iterator = studentList.iterator();
                            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                                Student studentDetails = iterator.next();
                    %>
                        <tr><td><%=studentDetails.getFirstname()%></td>
                            <td><%=studentDetails.getLastname()%></td>
                            <td><%=studentDetails.getEmail()%></td>
                            <td><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/edit?id=<%=studentDetails.getId()%>
                            &firstname=<%=studentDetails.getFirstname() %>&lastname=<%=studentDetails.getLastname()%>
                            &email=<%=studentDetails.getEmail()%>">Update</a>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/delete?id=<%=studentDetails.getId()%>">Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    <% 
                            }
                     }
                    %>
                </tbody>
                
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <footer class="text-center text-lg-start p-4">
          <div class="bg-primary text-center p-3">
            © 2021 Copyright:
            <a class="text-dark" href=""> SAiS Botswana</a>
          </div>
        </footer> 
    </body>
</html>
```

PS tl/dr I am able to insert data to table correctly but not retrieve

here is my jpa class object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="students")
public class Student {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    
    
    
    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(int id, String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Student(String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
        super();
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }


    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

here is the console log i received after server start:

```
INFO: Server startup in 3040 ms
nullhello
Aug 10, 2021 4:09:49 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.5.6.Final
Aug 10, 2021 4:09:50 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
Aug 10, 2021 4:09:50 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Aug 10, 2021 4:09:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/week05]
Aug 10, 2021 4:09:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=user1}
Aug 10, 2021 4:09:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Aug 10, 2021 4:09:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Aug 10, 2021 4:09:51 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
Aug 10, 2021 4:09:54 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@31a0e986] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: drop table if exists students
Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) engine=MyISAM
Aug 10, 2021 4:09:54 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@356bba04] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: create table students (id integer not null, email varchar(255), firstname varchar(255), lastname varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into students (email, firstname, lastname, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try This Way **

```
<%
    List<Student> List = listStudents.getlistStudents();
%>


        <%
            for (Student  st: List) {
                int id = st.getId();
            
        %>

               <tr><td><%=st.getFirstname()%></td>
                        <td><%=st.getLastname()%></td>
                        <td><%=st.getEmail()%></td>
                        <td><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/edit?id= 
                        <%=st.getId()%>
                        &firstname=<%=st.getFirstname() %>&lastname= 
                        <%=st.getLastname()%>
                        &email=<%=st.getEmail()%>">Update</a>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href=" 
                          <%=request.getContextPath()%>/delete?id= 
                          <%=st.getId()%>">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                <% 
                        }
                 }
                %>
```

> refrence [ShowAllFlat.jsp](https://github.com/sammulla47/SocietryManagementSystem/blob/master/Society/WebContent/ShowAllFlat.jsp)

Comment: liststudents is just a attribute name for variables from allstudents list object which calls getallstudents() in the servlet so i can't call `getlistStudents();` as the function doesn't exist which associates liststudents. I get a `listStudents cannot be resolved ` error when i run your code, thanks for trying